# Magento 2.3 Readiness Check Failing

Tags: magento2.3

Issue: Magento 2.3 Fresh install Web setup fails the following

PHP Settings Check *
PHP Extensions Check
Check Cron Scripts

How to reproduce
Install new blank default install of magento 2.3 **setup passes the readiness check.** 
From admin go to system -> web setup wizard. Click on extensions, select anything to install. it takes you to the readiness check window and fails the above.

I have been stuck on this for three weeks. I just dont get it. It passes for the install but then failed when trying to install an extension.

I put a phpinfo file in both the root and the setup folder both are exactly the same.

Any help would be very much appreciated. I did not have this problem with the 2.2x version.

php version 7.1.25

Comment: Are you updating magento or installing it or installing module?

Comment: Hi Aman, I updated the question with more details.

Comment: Yes its needs cron setup

Comment: I setup the cron job several ways, I setup the cron the same way that is working on other accounts.

Comment: if your cron is correctly set it will generate two files in `var` directory called `.setup_cronjob_status` and `.update_cronjob_status` if this two file is there your are ready to go

Comment: yes those files are being generated every minute

Comment: Then you should not get above error what is the file permission of this files.

Comment: I am adding it to official answer please mark it complete by clicking on tick mark and upvote it.

Comment: Thank you it was incorrect permissions on the .setup_cronjob_status and .update_cronjob_status. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: If its resolved your issue please accept posted answer by clicking on tick mark so that it will help other's to resolve there issue and upvote by clicking on upper arrow of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For running websetup wizard cron setup must be needed.

Here is official doc to setup cron:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

For your problem if you are setup cron correctly there must be two files generated in `var` directory called `.setup_cronjob_status` and `.update_cronjob_status` if this two files are generated you are ready to run websetup wizard. Also check the permission of both generated file is correct or not it should be `644`